# Unit Tests don't load. The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

My unit tests do not run at all. They display the following the error: "Unit Tests don't load. The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

I have gone into debug and made sure all the symbols load. I am running VS2010 with SP1 installed and have re-installed many times.

Comment: FIXED! I had VS2013 installed. Somehow this confuses VS2010. I un-installed VS2013. Restarted and it works :)

Comment: Please either delete this question or add your solution as an answer and accept it. That way a future person when finding this question from a google search will clearly see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had VS2013 installed.  Somehow this confused VS2010. I un-installed VS2013. Restarted and VS2010  unit tests worked again.